# overloading + operator in a polynomial linked list

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so i am trying to overload the + operator in a single linked list the problem is that my program crashes each time i try to run the code.in my code i tried to add the coefficients with the same exponent.And in case the exponents are not equal i tried to add the different two terms to the resulting polynomial. 
The insert function adds the term in a sorted order from higher exponent to lower one

```
 polynomials polynomials:: operator + (const polynomials&p )const{
 node*current=head;
 node*temp=p.head;
 polynomials poly;
 node *newnode=0;
 while(current!=0||temp!=0)
 {
    if(current->exponent==temp->exponent)
    {
       newnode->exponent=current->exponent;
        newnode->coefficient=current->coefficient+temp->coefficient;
        poly.insert(*newnode);
        newnode=newnode->link;
    }
    else
    {
        if(current->exponent > temp->exponent)
      { newnode->exponent=current->exponent;
        newnode->coefficient=current->coefficient;
        poly.insert(*newnode);
        newnode=newnode->link;    
        newnode->exponent=temp->exponent;
        newnode->coefficient=temp->coefficient;
        poly.insert(*newnode);
        }
        else
        {

        newnode->exponent=temp->exponent;
        newnode->coefficient=temp->coefficient;
        poly.insert(*newnode);
        newnode=newnode->link;    
        newnode->exponent=current->exponent;
        newnode->coefficient=current->coefficient;
        poly.insert(*newnode);


        }

    }
    current=current->link;
    temp=temp->link;
 }

 return poly;}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `newnode = 0` and you deference it...

Comment: I did actually use a debugger and the problem seem to be in this line newnode->exponent=current->exponent; i am not really sure why?

Comment: Did you look at the values of your variables when your debugger broke in to your program? Did you single-step through your program, and specifically this merge code, with simply lists that exhibit the problem? you're apt to find a lot more doing that.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see.

```
while(current!=0||temp!=0)
```

followed by

```
if(current->exponent==temp->exponent)
```

is not right. If one of the pointers is `nullptr`, you end up dereferencing a `nullptr`.

I would try

```
while(current != nullptr && temp != nullptr)
```

Comment: i changed but the program still crashes

Comment: @Mhaalazri, it looks like you have more than one problem in your code. Using a debugger might be your best option.